# php update successful but not updating the databse

Tags: php, mysql

I got problem with this code. I've tried so many possible solution but still no update in phpmyadmin. The code run successfully through the footer since it say "Successfully Updated" but still no changes

```html
<?php
if ($_POST){
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "pass123");

if (!$con){die('Could not connect:' . mysql_error());}
mysql_select_db("testing", $con) or die('Error:' . mysql_error());

$entry = $_GET['entry'];
$branch_id = $_POST['branch_id'];
$outletname = $_POST['outletname'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$q11a = $_POST['q11a'];
$q12a = $_POST['q12a'];
$q13a = $_POST['q13a'];
$q14a = $_POST['q14a'];
$q15a = $_POST['q15a'];
$q16a = $_POST['q16a'];
$q17a = $_POST['q17a'];
$q18a = $_POST['q18a'];
$q19a = $_POST['q19a'];
$q20a = $_POST['q20a'];
$q21a = $_POST['q21a'];
$q22a = $_POST['q22a'];
$q23a = $_POST['q23a'];
$q24a = $_POST['q24a'];
$q25a = $_POST['q25a'];
$q26a = $_POST['q26a'];
$q27a = $_POST['q27a'];
$q28a = $_POST['q28a'];
$q29a = $_POST['q29a'];
$q30a = $_POST['q30a'];
$q31a = $_POST['q31a'];
$q32a = $_POST['q32a'];
$q33a = $_POST['q33a'];
$q34a = $_POST['q34a'];
$q35a = $_POST['q35a'];
$q36a = $_POST['q36a'];
$q37a = $_POST['q37a'];
$q38a = $_POST['q38a'];
$q39a = $_POST['q39a'];
$q40a = $_POST['q40a'];
$q41a = $_POST['q41a'];
$q42a = $_POST['q42a'];
$q43a = $_POST['q43a'];
$q44a = $_POST['q44a'];
$q45a = $_POST['q45a'];
$q46a = $_POST['q46a'];
$q47a = $_POST['q47a'];
$q48a = $_POST['q48a'];
$q49a = $_POST['q49a'];
$q50a = $_POST['q50a'];
$q51a = $_POST['q51a'];
$q52a = $_POST['q52a'];
$q53a = $_POST['q53a'];
$q54a = $_POST['q54a'];
$q55a = $_POST['q55a'];
$q56a = $_POST['q56a'];
$q57a = $_POST['q57a'];
$q58a = $_POST['q58a'];
$q59a = $_POST['q59a'];
$q60a = $_POST['q60a'];
$q61a = $_POST['q61a'];
$q62a = $_POST['q62a'];
$q63a = $_POST['q63a'];
$q64a = $_POST['q64a'];
$q65a = $_POST['q65a'];
$q66a = $_POST['q66a'];
$q67a = $_POST['q67a'];
$q68a = $_POST['q68a'];
$q69a = $_POST['q69a'];
$q70a = $_POST['q70a'];
$q71a = $_POST['q71a'];
$q72a = $_POST['q72a'];
$q73a = $_POST['q73a'];
$q74a = $_POST['q74a'];
$q75a = $_POST['q75a'];
$q76a = $_POST['q76a'];
$q78a = $_POST['q78a'];
$q78a1 = $_POST['q78a1'];
$q79a = $_POST['q79a'];
$q79a1 = $_POST['q79a1'];
$q80a = $_POST['q80a'];
$q81a = $_POST['q81a'];
$q82a = $_POST['q82a'];
$q83a = $_POST['q83a'];
$q84a = $_POST['q84a'];
$q85a = $_POST['q85a'];
$timein = $_POST['timein'];
$HOR = $_POST['HOR'];
$MODa = $_POST['MODa'];
$KL = $_POST['KL'];
$ateambox = $_POST['ateambox'];
$box35 = $_POST['box35'];
$box36 = $_POST['box36'];
$box41 = $_POST['box41'];
$box50 = $_POST['box50'];
$box53 = $_POST['box53'];
$box54 = $_POST['box54'];
$box55 = $_POST['box55'];
$box61a = $_POST['box61a'];
$box61aa = $_POST['box61aa'];
$box61b = $_POST['box61b'];
$box61bb = $_POST['box61bb'];
$box61c = $_POST['box61c'];
$box61cc =$_POST['box61cc'];
$box61d = $_POST['box61d'];
$box61dd = $_POST['box61dd'];
$box61e = $_POST['box61e'];
$box61ee = $_POST['box61ee'];
$box73a = $_POST['box73a'];
$box73b = $_POST['box73b'];
$box73c = $_POST['box73c'];
$box74a = $_POST['box74a'];
$box74b = $_POST['box74b'];
$box74c = $_POST['box74c'];
$box74d = $_POST['box74d'];
$box74e = $_POST['box74e'];
$box74f = $_POST['box74f'];
$box74g = $_POST['box74g'];
$box74h = $_POST['box74h'];
$box74i = $_POST['box74i'];
$box74j = $_POST['box74j'];
$box75a = $_POST['box75a'];
$box75b = $_POST['box75b'];
$box75c = $_POST['box75c'];
$box75d = $_POST['box75d'];
$box75e = $_POST['box75e'];
$box75f = $_POST['box75f'];
$box75g = $_POST['box75g'];
$box75h = $_POST['box75h'];
$box75i = $_POST['box75i'];
$box75j = $_POST['box75j'];
$box75k = $_POST['box75k'];
$box75l = $_POST['box75l'];
$box75m = $_POST['box75m'];
$box75n = $_POST['box75n'];
$box75o = $_POST['box75o'];
$box75p = $_POST['box75p'];
$box75q = $_POST['box75q'];
$box75r = $_POST['box75r'];
$box78a = $_POST['box78a'];
$box78b = $_POST['box78b'];
$box78c = $_POST['box78c'];
$box78d = $_POST['box78d'];
$box78e = $_POST['box78e'];
$box78f = $_POST['box78f'];
$box78g = $_POST['box78g'];
$box78h = $_POST['box78h'];
$box78i = $_POST['box78i'];
$box78j = $_POST['box78j'];
$box78k = $_POST['box78k'];
$box78l = $_POST['box78l'];
$box78m = $_POST['box78m'];
$box79a = $_POST['box79a'];
$box79b = $_POST['box79b'];
$box79c = $_POST['box79c'];
$box79d = $_POST['box79d'];
$box91a = $_POST['box91a'];
$box91b = $_POST['box91b'];
$box91c = $_POST['box91c'];
$box92a = $_POST['box92a'];
$box92b = $_POST['box92b'];

if ($q11a == -1){
$naarrival = $naarrival + 1;
}
if ($q12a == -1){
$naarrival = $naarrival + 1;
}
if ($q14a == -1){
$naarrival = $naarrival + 1;
}
if ($q15a == -1){
$naarrival = $naarrival + 1;
}
if ($q26a == -1){
$nadining = $nadining + 1;
}
if ($q31a == -1){
$nadining = $nadining + 1;
}
if ($q32a == -1){
$nadining = $nadining + 1;
}
if ($q44a == -1){
$nadining = $nadining + 1;
}
if ($q45a == -1){
$nadining = $nadining + 1;
}
if ($q78a == -1){
$naproduct = $naproduct + 1;
}
if ($q81a == -1){
$naproduct = $naproduct + 1;
}
if ($q83a == -1){
$napayment = $napayment + 1;
}

$arrival_na1 = $naarrival;
$arrival_ppna1 = 14 - $arrival_na1;
$totalarrival = $q11a + $q12a + $q13a + $q14a + $q15a + $q16a + $q17a + $q18a;
$arrival_score1 = $totalarrival / $arrival_ppna1 *100;

$dining_na1 = $nadining;
$dining_ppna1 = 31 - $dining_na1;
$totaldining = $q19a + $q20a + $q21a + $q22a + $q23a + $q24a + $q25a + $q26a + $q27a + $q28a + $q29a + $q30a + $q31a + $q32a + $q33a + $q34a + $q35a + $q36a + $q37a + $q38a + $q39a + $q40a + $q41a + $q42a + $q43a + $q44a + $q45a + $q46a + $q47a + $q48a + $q49a;
$dining_score1 = $totaldining / $dining_ppna1 *100;
    
$ordering_na1 = $naordering;
$ordering_ppna1 = 28 - $ordering_na1;
$totalordering = $q50a + $q51a + $q52a + $q53a + $q54a + $q55a + $q56a + $q57a;
$ordering_score1 = $totalordering / $ordering_ppna1 *100;

$product_na1 = $naproduct;
$product_ppna1 = 47 - $product_na1;
$totalproduct = $q58a + $q59a + $q60a + $q61a + $q62a + $q63a + $q64a + $q65a + $q66a + $q67a + $q68a + $q69a + $q70a + $q71a + $q72a + $q73a + $q74a + $q75a + $q76a + $q78a + $q78a1 + $q79a + $q79a1 + $q80a + $q81a;
$product_score1 = $totalproduct / $product_ppna1 *100;

$payment_na1 = $napayment;
$payment_ppna1 = 6 - $payment_na1;
$totalpayment = $q82a + $q83a + $q84a + $q85a;
$payment_score1 = $totalpayment / $payment_ppna1 *100;

$totalattentiveness1 = ($q16a + $q18a + $q51a + $q52a + $q55a + $q57a + $q85a) / 19 * 100;
$totalaccuracy1 = ($q50a + $q54a + $q56a) / 8 * 100;
$totalspeed1 = $q53a / 8 * 100;
$totalfriendliness1 = ($q17a + $q84a) / 6 * 100;
$totalpresentation1 = ($q63a + $q64a + $q67a + $q72a) / 5 * 100;
$totaltaste1 = ($q59a + $q61a + $q70a + $q71a + $q79a + $q80a) / 14 * 100;
$totalquality1 = ($q58a + $q60a + $q62a + $q65a + $q66a + $q68a + $q69a + $q73a + $q74a + $q75a + $q76a + $q78a + $q78a1 + $q79a1 + $q81a) / 28 * 100;

$total1 = $arrival_na1 + $dining_na1 + $ordering_na1 + $product_na1 + $payment_na1;
$total2 = $arrival_ppna1 + $dining_ppna1 + $ordering_ppna1 + $product_ppna1 + $payment_ppna1;
$total3 = $totalarrival + $totaldining + $totalordering + $totalproduct + $totalpayment;
$percentage = ($total3 / $total2) * 100;

if ($percentage >= 86) {
        $grade = "A";
} else if ($percentage >= 70) {
        $grade = "B";
} else if ($percentage >= 55) {
        $grade = "C";
} else {
        $grade = "D";
}

mysql_select_db("testing", $con) or die('Error:' .mysql_error());

$insert_query = "UPDATE a_team SET
date='$date',
q11a='$q11a',
q12a='$q12a',
q13a='$q13a',
q14a='$q14a',
q15a='$q15a',
q16a='$q16a',
q17a='$q17a',
q18a='$q18a',
q19a='$q19a',
q20a='$q20a',
q21a='$q21a',
q22a='$q22a',
q23a='$q23a',
q24a='$q24a',
q25a='$q25a',
q26a='$q26a',
q27a='$q27a',
q28a='$q28a',
q29a='$q29a',
q30a='$q30a',
q31a='$q31a',
q32a='$q32a',
q33a='$q33a',
q34a='$q34a',
q35a='$q35a',
q36a='$q36a',
q37a='$q37a',
q38a='$q38a',
q39a='$q39a',
q40a='$q40a',
q41a='$q41a',
q42a='$q42a',
q43a='$q43a',
q44a='$q44a',
q45a='$q45a',
q46a='$q46a',
q47a='$q47a',
q48a='$q48a',
q49a='$q49a',
q50a='$q50a',
q51a='$q51a',
q52a='$q52a',
q53a='$q53a',
q54a='$q54a',
q55a='$q55a',
q56a='$q56a',
q57a='$q57a',
q58a='$q58a',
q59a='$q59a',
q60a='$q60a',
q61a='$q61a',
q62a='$q62a',
q63a='$q63a',
q64a='$q64a',
q65a='$q65a',
q66a='$q66a',
q67a='$q67a',
q68a='$q68a',
q69a='$q69a',
q70a='$q70a',
q71a='$q71a',
q72a='$q72a',
q73a='$q73a',
q74a='$q74a',
q75a='$q75a',
q76a='$q76a',
q78a='$q78a',
q78a1='$q78a1',
q79a='$q79a',
q79a1='$q79a1',
q80a='$q80a',
q81a='$q81a',
q82a='$q82a',
q83a='$q83a',
q84a='$q84a',
q85a='$q85a',
totalarrival='$totalarrival',
arrival_score1='$arrival_score1',
totaldining='$totaldining',
dining_score1='$dining_score1',
totalordering='$totalordering',
ordering_score1='$ordering_score1',
totalproduct='$totalproduct',
product_score1='$product_score1',
totalpayment='$totalpayment',
payment_score1='$payment_score1',
totalattentiveness1='$totalattentiveness1',
totalaccuracy1='$totalaccuracy1',
totalspeed1='$totalspeed1',
totalfriendliness1='$totalfriendliness1',
totalpresentation1='$totalpresentation1',
totaltaste1='$totaltaste1',
totalquality1='$totalquality1',
timein='$timein',
HOR='$HOR',
MODa='$MODa',
KL='$KL',
ateambox='$ateambox',
box35='$box35',
box36='$box36',
box41='$box41',
box50='$box50',
box53='$box53',
box54='$box54',
box55='$box55',
box61a='$box61a',
box61aa='$box61aa',
box61b='$box61b',
box61bb='$box61bb',
box61c='$box61c',
box61cc='$box61cc',
box61d='$box61d',
box61dd='$box61dd',
box61e='$box61e',
box61ee='$box61ee',
box73a='$box73a',
box73b='$box73b',
box73c='$box73c',
box74a='$box74a',
box74b='$box74b',
box74c='$box74c',
box74d='$box74d',
box74e='$box74e',
box74f='$box74f',
box74g='$box74g',
box74h='$box74h',
box74i='$box74i',
box74j='$box74j',
box75a='$box75a',
box75b='$box75b',
box75c='$box75c',
box75d='$box75d',
box75e='$box75e',
box75f='$box75f',
box75g='$box75g',
box75h='$box75h',
box75i='$box75i',
box75j='$box75j',
box75k='$box75k',
box75l='$box75l',
box75m='$box75m',
box75n='$box75n',
box75o='$box75o',
box75p='$box75p',
box75q='$box75q',
box75r='$box75r',
box78a='$box78a',
box78b='$box78b',
box78c='$box78c',
box78d='$box78d',
box78e='$box78e',
box78f='$box78f',
box78g='$box78g',
box78h='$box78h',
box78i='$box78i',
box78j='$box78j',
box78k='$box78k',
box78l='$box78l',
box78m='$box78m',
box79a='$box79a',
box79b='$box79b',
box79c='$box79c',
box79d='$box79d',
box91a='$box91a',
box91b='$box91b',
box91c='$box91c',
box92a='$box92a',
box92b='$box92b',
arrival_na1='$arrival_na1',
arrival_ppna1='$arrival_ppna1',
dining_na1='$dining_na1',
dining_ppna1='$dining_ppna1',
ordering_na1='$ordering_na1',
ordering_ppna1='$ordering_ppna1',
product_na1='$product_na1',
product_ppna1='$product_ppna1',
payment_na1='$payment_na1',
payment_ppna1='$payment_ppna1',
total1='$total1',
total2='$total2',
total3='$total3',
percentage='$percentage',
grade='$grade' WHERE entry='$entry'";
mysql_query($insert_query) or die('Error:' . mysql_error());
mysql_close($con);
}
?>
```

Comment: You can't use `POST` and `GET` method at the same time. So make on `hidden` field and store your `GET` method value `entry`. While submission get your value using `$_POST['entry']`. Your problem will be solved.

Comment: @Yash this is actually not true. Try it out: have a form with method=post and in the action have a get parameter. In php both $_GET and $_POST will be populated. The OP may have mixed up the 2, but it is possible to use both at the same time.

Comment: Try to avoid all `mysql_` function. It has been removed in PHP7. Try to use `PDO`.

Comment: @Shadow! we can use both method, that's true. but this is not proper way to implement to be a good coding practice we need to use either of them.

Comment: @Yash, I've change the GET to POST but still didn't solve the problem..

Comment: Code seems ok, you just echo your query on browser. copy it and run on phpmyadmin. try to change query if not worked. You will be solve your problem.

Comment: @Yash, sorry for ask, may I know how to echo query on phpmyadmin? I'm still newbie in this..

Comment: @MHafizieMIsa use `echo $insert_query;`. it will show the output of query what you want to execute. then you can run on phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you insert query give the correct query or not

echo $insert_qury="update query ";

and copy the output of insert query and test manually to past on sql in table it it update correctly then you query is correct and your error may be on "mysql_query"

Answer (score -1):

You have put everything inside single quote...
Try this:

```
$insert_query = "UPDATE a_team SET
date='".$date."',
q11a='".$q11a."',
q12a='".$q12a."',..... WHERE entry='".$entry."'";
```

Comment: Every field value is enclosed by single quotes in the OP. In some instances unnecessarily.

Comment: @DipanwitaKundu, Tried but still the same. It can run but still no changes made to phpmyadmin.. T.T

Comment: Please echo the query & either run it manually from phpmyadmin or send me the query.

Comment: @DipanwitaKundu, may I know how to run it manually from phpmyadmin? I'm still new in this..

Comment: go to sql tab in phpmyadmin. paste the query you have...then run otherwise send it to me.